# Azure DevOps Pipeline: Set version per branch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am new to Azure DevOps Pipeline, so I'm still learning. I need some help in creating a workaround in setting the versions of the packages that we'd like to run through the pipeline.

On our repository, we have DEV branch, UAT branch, and Main (which serves as our PROD branch). So what we plan is every time there's a pull request sent to UAT branch, a package will be published and deployed to our UAT environment. Same way when a pull request is created on Main (ideally always be coming from UAT branch), a package will be published and deployed to our PROD environment.

What we'd like to happen is to have *set the patch version* every time a pull request is created.
For example, there were currently 4 pull request approved on UAT branch, so the version should be 1.0.4.
At 1.0.4, the code was approved to proceed to PROD environment, so a pull request was created, and we are expecting the 1.0.1 version to be published since it was the first time to merge it on Main.

Thank you!

What I currently have is this, but it's just making 1.0.5 version published on PROD env:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Automating the correct semantic version for packages is definitely tricky. Especially when factoring in when to increment the major/minor.

I'm not sure if i'd follow your PR count method, but if it works for you then you can leverage the [Azure DevOps CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-pr-list) in your pipeline to count how many PR's have merged to main.